# How a Spark Streaming application be loaded and run?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

hi i am new to spark and spark streaming.
from the official document i could understand how to manipulate input data and save them.

the problem is the quick example of Spark Streaming [quick example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#a-quick-example)made me confuse

i knew the the job should get data from the DStream you have setted and do something on them, but since its running 24/7. how will the application be loaded and run?

will it run every n seconds or just run once at the beginning and then enter the cycle of [read-process-loop]?

BTW, i am using python, so i checked the python code of that example, if its the latter case, how spark's executor knews the which code snipnet is the loop part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark Streaming is actually a microbatch processing. That means each interval, which you can customize, a new batch is executed.

Look at the coding of the example, which you have mentioned

```
sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "NetworkWordCount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,1)
```

You define a streaming context, which a micro-batch interval of 1 second.

That is the subsequent coding, which uses the streaming context

```
lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
...
```

gets executed every second.

The streaming process gets initially triggerd by this line

```
ssc.start()             # Start the computation
```

Comment: my processing require my sending the data to my own storage, so i need to initialize the connection at first, which should i place these codes?

Comment: read http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams there are design patterns described regarding your question